# Каким образом, я могу загнать данный код в цикл?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код, написанная функция.
но решительно не понимаю как сжать так скажем блоки каждой снежинки, в блоки функций и что бы они одновременно работали
До этого делал функцию, но получалось что падала только одна снежинка, а как сделать что бы функция запускалась и работала одновременно с 5-ю, не понял

```
import simple_draw as sd
import random as rd

# n = int(input('Введите количество снежинок '))
sd.resolution = (1200, 600)
coord_list = []


def random_coordinate(n=5):
    for i in range(n):
        x = rd.randint(100, 1100)
        coord_list.append(x)
        y = rd.randint(100, 550)
        coord_list.append(y)
    print(coord_list)
    return coord_list


random_coordinate()


def snowflake_alone(x, y, x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, x_3, y_3, x_4, y_4):
    length_random = rd.randint(20, 60)
    length_random_1 = rd.randint(20, 60)
    length_random_2 = rd.randint(20, 60)
    length_random_3 = rd.randint(20, 60)
    length_random_4 = rd.randint(20, 60)
    sd.start_drawing()
    while True:

        if y > 30:
            point = sd.get_point(x, y)
            sd.snowflake(point, length=length_random)
            sd.snowflake(point, length=length_random, color=sd.background_color)
            y -= rd.uniform(5, 15)
            x = rd.uniform(0.9, 1.1) * x
            point = sd.get_point(x, y)
            sd.snowflake(point, length=length_random)

        if y_1 > 30:
            point_1 = sd.get_point(x_1, y_1)
            sd.snowflake(point_1, length=length_random_1)
            sd.snowflake(point_1, length=length_random_1, color=sd.background_color)
            y_1 -= rd.uniform(5, 15)
            x_1 = rd.uniform(0.9, 1.1) * x_1
            point_1 = sd.get_point(x_1, y_1)
            sd.snowflake(point_1, length=length_random_1)

        if y_2 > 30:
            point_2 = sd.get_point(x_2, y_2)
            sd.snowflake(point_2, length=length_random_2)
            sd.snowflake(point_2, length=length_random_2, color=sd.background_color)
            y_2 -= rd.uniform(5, 15)
            x_2 = rd.uniform(0.9, 1.1) * x_2
            point_2 = sd.get_point(x_2, y_2)
            sd.snowflake(point_2, length=length_random_2)

        if y_3 > 30:
            point_3 = sd.get_point(x_3, y_3)
            sd.snowflake(point_3, length=length_random_3)
            sd.snowflake(point_3, length=length_random_3, color=sd.background_color)
            y_3 -= rd.uniform(5, 15)
            x_3 = rd.uniform(0.9, 1.1) * x_3
            point_3 = sd.get_point(x_3, y_3)
            sd.snowflake(point_3, length=length_random_3)

        if y_4 > 30:
            point_4 = sd.get_point(x_4, y_4)
            sd.snowflake(point_4, length=length_random_4)
            sd.snowflake(point_4, length=length_random_4, color=sd.background_color)
            y_4 -= rd.uniform(5, 15)
            x_4 = rd.uniform(0.9, 1.1) * x_4
            point_4 = sd.get_point(x_4, y_4)
            sd.snowflake(point_4, length=length_random_4)

        sd.finish_drawing()
        sd.sleep(0.1)

snowflake_alone(*coord_list)
sd.pause()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас много повторяющегося кода.

Чтобы было проще работать с однотипными объектами объединим их в структуры а структуры - в списки.

Тогда можно будет вынести код в функции и обрабатывать списки объектов циклом.

Для начала можно объединить координаты `[x, y]` в список либо `tuple`:

```
def random_coordinate(n=5):
    for i in range(n):
        x = rd.randint(100, 1100)
        y = rd.randint(100, 550)
        coord_list.append([x, y])
    print(coord_list)
    return coord_list
```

Вынесем повторяющийся код в функцию

```
def draw_once(coords, length_random: float):
    x, y = coords
    if y > 30:
        point = sd.get_point(x, y)
        sd.snowflake(point, length=length_random)
        sd.snowflake(point, length=length_random, color=sd.background_color)
        y -= rd.uniform(5, 15)
        x = rd.uniform(0.9, 1.1) * x
        point = sd.get_point(x, y)
        sd.snowflake(point, length=length_random)
    
    return (x, y)
```

Преобразуем `length_random_*` в список

```
length_random = [rd.randint(20, 60) for _ in range(5)]
```

Теперь можно попробовать заменить повторяющийся код циклом

```
def snowflake_alone(coord_list):
    
    curr_coords = coord_list.copy()
    length_random = [rd.randint(20, 60) for _ in range(5)]
    
    sd.start_drawing()
    while True:
        new_coords = []
        
        for idx, coord in enumerate(curr_coords):
            new_coord = draw_once(coord, length_random[idx])
            new_coords.append(new_coord)
        
        curr_coords = new_coords

        sd.finish_drawing()
        sd.sleep(0.1)
```

Ну и соберем все вместе:

```
from typing import List
import simple_draw as sd
import random as rd


def random_coordinate(n=5):
    for i in range(n):
        x = rd.randint(100, 1100)
        y = rd.randint(100, 550)
        coord_list.append([x, y])
    print(coord_list)
    return coord_list


def draw_once(coords: List[float], length_random: float) -> List[float]:
    x, y = coords
    if y > 30:
        point = sd.get_point(x, y)
        sd.snowflake(point, length=length_random)
        sd.snowflake(point, length=length_random, color=sd.background_color)
        y -= rd.uniform(5, 15)
        x = rd.uniform(0.9, 1.1) * x
        point = sd.get_point(x, y)
        sd.snowflake(point, length=length_random)
    
    return [x, y]


def snowflake_alone(coord_list):
    
    curr_coords = coord_list.copy()
    coord_count = len(coord_list)
    length_random = [rd.randint(20, 60) for _ in range(coord_count)]
    
    sd.start_drawing()
    while True:
        new_coords = []
        
        for idx, coord in enumerate(curr_coords):
            new_coord = draw_once(coord, length_random[idx])
            new_coords.append(new_coord)
        
        curr_coords = new_coords

        sd.finish_drawing()
        sd.sleep(0.1)


# n = int(input('Введите количество снежинок '))
sd.resolution = (1200, 600)
coord_list = []
random_coordinate()

snowflake_alone(coord_list)
sd.pause()
```

---

**Внимание**: код не проверял, могут быть ошибки

Comment: Спасибо огромное вам!